# Add a site to Silverlight permissions tab

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, configuration, permissions, video-streaming

I have an intranet site that uses a Silverlight application to take pictures with the WebCam of the computer.

Testing the site on a Development environment works fine but testing the site on a QA environment wont display any image.

Looking more in deep on both sites I see that the Silverlight permissions tab has define "ALLOW" to the Development URL but the QA url does not appear at all on the permissions tab.

**How can I add the URL of the QA site to the permissions tab on the Silverlight Permissions tab ?**

I am using the Silverlight 4.0.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- regedit
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppDataLow\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\Permissions`
- create new item
- create new Dword
- Name: `Allow3DOnInsecureDisplayDrivers`, Value: `11`

And you will get what you want.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question.