# How to create a registry that allows the Silverlight applications access to camera and mic

Tags: c#, silverlight, registry, trusted

I need to know how can I create a registry that allow the Silverlight applications access to camera and mic.

Scenario:

I have a Silverlight application that start the WebCam, before it works it shows a Silverlight dialog asking if the user allows the application to access it.

Finally I'm creating a desktop app that loads the Silverlight application in a web browser. I want my application desktop to creates a registry or something like that to allow this access and stopping to show the Silverlight dialog.

Exists some solution to this?? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: For someone who has the same issue here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17829842/2882534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who has the same issue here is the solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17829842/2882534

Just create a subkey named whit your Url plus port(ex: `http://localhost:54895`) at the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppDataLow\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\Permissions

After that, create a registry named WebcamAndMicrophone with DWORD and value 11.

Shazan! The silverlight dialog is not more necessary.

Tutorial to manipulate registrys:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4808/All-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-Registry-with-C-P